# c++ do children fit in their parents slots?

Tags: c++, class, object, parent

In my java class i remember making a barn class that held animal class objects, and my chicken and cow classes (which were children of the animal class) would fit into the barn as if they were their parents.

i was wondering if c++ also allowed this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. The general concept is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

One issue to be aware of that arises in C++ but not in Java is slicing: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: could i avoid slicing by using a parent pointer to point to a child?

Comment: @TylerJantzen: Yes you can. Pointers and references are fine. As long as you don't copy *by value*, there will be no slicing.

Answer (score 1):

In your java example you probably held a reference to a `Animal` class. In such case you can use any descendant class of `Animal` class in that reference.

The same is with C++, if you use a pointer to the instance. Like:

```
class Barn
{
public:
    Animal* animal;
};

class Animal
{
public:
};

class Chicken : public Animal
{
public:
};
```

The `Barn::animal` can reference even `Chicken` class.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works just as well with a reference.